# How can I load a CSV file with columns spanning multiple lines using DBMS_CLOUD to ADW?

Tags: oracle, oracle-autonomous-db

I am trying to load huge number of rows of data from a CSV file into ADW tables. The CSV files are already in the object storage and I am using DBMS_CLOUD.COPY_DATA to load data from CSV file to my table.

The challenge is when the columns contains multiple lines.

Here's the short sample of the column with multiple lines which I stored in test.csv file:

```
O_NO, O_DESC, O_DATE
A001,"This is the first 
multi-line record", 28-Jun-2020 13:09:06
A002, "This is the second
multi-line 

record", 28-Jun-2020 14:56:07
```

As you could see, there are two rows here, but both has the description column (O_DESC) filled with multiple lines, enclosed in the double-quote sign (").

What is the parameter that I need to put in the format parameter?

Here are the steps I use for creating the table and DBMS_CLOUD.COPY_DATA procedure to load CSV content but it fails:

```
CREATE TABLE AW_TEST
(
   O_NO VARCHAR2(8),
   O_DESC VARCHAR2(200),
   O_DATE DATE
);

BEGIN
 DBMS_CLOUD.COPY_DATA(
    table_name =>'AW_TEST'
    , credential_name =>'AW_CRED_NAME'
    , file_uri_list => 'https://objectstorage.us-ashburn-1.oraclecloud.com/n/mynamespace/b/mybucket/o/test.csv'
    , format => json_object('type' value 'CSV', 'delimiter' value ',', 'skipheaders' value '1', 'dateformat' value 'DD-Mon-YYYY HH24:MI:SS', 'blankasnull' value 'true', 'recorddelimiter' value '''\r\n''')
 );
END;
/
```

How can I load these multi-line columns?

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'type' value 'csv with embedded' on the parameter list as below:

```
begin
    DBMS_CLOUD.COPY_DATA (
        table_name => 'AW_TEST',
        credential_name => 'AW_CRED_NAME',
        file_uri_list => 'https://objectstorage.us-ashburn-1.oraclecloud.com/n/mynamespace/b/mybucket/o/test.csv',
        format => json_object('type' value 'csv with embedded', 'delimiter' value ',', 'skipheaders' value 1, 'dateformat' value 'DD-Mon-YYYY HH24:MI:SS', 'blankasnull' value 'true')
    );
end;
/
```